# incrementing a nested list

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

i have a nested list in python that i need to access. as i access it i need to increment my way through this list.
eg:

```
list= [[100, 320,  440, 'style_F'], [130, 200, -420, 'style_A']]
```

this is a list of locations and style of drawing. 
my code is this:

```
def draw_buildings(list):
c=0
innerlist=list[c]
wide = innerlist[0]
height = innerlist[1]
xcoord = innerlist[2]
style = innerlist[3]

def draw(w,h,x,style):
 while c<len(list):
    draw(wide,height, xcoord, style)
    c+=1
```

now the variable C does increase - but only when cycling through the lists - example when i add the commands

```
        print c
        print wide
        print height
        print xcoord
        print style
```

i would get the following:

```
1
100
320
440
style_F
2
100
320
440
style_F
```

so the number is going up, but it's not going through the nested lists

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do Not use list as a variable name

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. But you might want to use a dictionary rather than a nested list, because you always store the same datas, so there's no need for an inner list.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have

```
c = 0
innerlist = list[c]
```

That means that `innerlist` always ends up being the first item of the outer list. What you really want is to update the values every time. Also, use a `for` loop instead of that `while` loop - it's more pythonic:

**Note: Don't use `list`as a variable name - it's a builtin function that should not just be overwritten - I named the variable `outerlist` instead.**

```
for innerlist in outerlist:
    wide, height, xcoord, style = innerlist # Yes, you can do that...
    draw(wide, height, xcoord, style)
```

As a bonus, you can use `*args` here:

```
for innerlist in outerlist:
    draw(*innerlist)
```

Comment: -1 for not correcting the OP on using list as a variable name

Comment: Fine, I'll add that :D

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list like this:

```
for sublist in list:
    wide, height, xcoord, style = sublist
    print c
    print wide
    print height
    print xcoord
    print style
```